# Ventanas diálogo solo funcionan al refrescar la página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, diálogo

Éste es el [index de la pagina](http://judasniper.neocities.org/). Al seleccionar el botón antibioticos, se abre la página antibioticos.html con un ***ul*** con las lista de productos, al hacer clic en alguno se debería mostrar una ventana *dialog* que está contenida en la misma página. Pero ésta no abre.

Pero si yo entro direccto al enlace de la [página de antibióticos](http://judasniper.neocities.org/antibioticos.html), ahi si funciona. ¿Qué puede ser y cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Éste es mi código

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>jQuery Mobile Docs - Dialogs</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.1.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-docs.css"/>

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.1.js"></script>




<!-- Start of first page: #Principal -->
<div data-role="page" id="one">
  <div data-role="header" >
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-left">Inicio</a>
    <h1>Antibioticos.</h1>
  </div><!-- /header -->

  <div data-role="content" >    
    <ul data-role="listview">
      <li><a href="#amoxicilina">Amoxicilina</a></li>
      <li><a href="#cefalexina">Cefalexina</a></li>
      <li><a href="#doxiciclina">Doxicilina</a></li>
      <li><a href="#metronidazol">Metronidazol</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tmpsmx">TMP-SMX</a></li>
      <li><a href="#amoxicilina" data-prefetch> ... </a></li>
    </ul>   

  </div><!-- /content -->

  <div data-role="footer" >
    <h1>© 2016 Pediadosis, Todos los derechos reservados. </h1>
  </div><!-- /footer -->
</div>
<!-- /page Principal -->

<!-- Start of  page: #Amoxicilina -->
<div data-role="dialog" id="amoxicilina">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
    <h2>Amoxilina..</h2>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
    <h1>Amoxilina</h1>
    <div class="blockquote">
      <p>DES/ Atibiotico de amplio espectro.
        <br><br>IND Infeccion del tracto respiratorio, urogenital y gastrointestinal, de la region ORL, de la piel, infeciones geniológicas, gonorrea, leptospirosis, fiebre tofoidea.</p>
      <p>Dosis. 50 mg/kg/dia cada 8 horas</p>

    </div>  
    <div  id="mgAmox">Miligramos</div>
    <div  id="mlAmox">Mililitros</div>
    <hr>
    <input id ="amox" type="range" value="12" min="0" max="50" step="0.5" data-theme="c" data-highlight="true"/>
    <a href="#index" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">Regresar</a>
```

Comment: El segundo enlace no funciona. Deberías incluir el código relevante directamente en la pregunta en lugar de añadir enlaces a sitios externos. Lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en el centro de ayuda y edita la pregunta.

Comment: Si tienes información  nueva para la pregunta debes añadirla dándole al botón de [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/20307/edit) que encontrarás en la parte inferior izquierda de la pregunta. He añadido los nuevos datos por ti, por favor, borra las respuestas que publicaste

Comment: El problema que se te presenta es porque tu página no se redirecciona cuando pulsas en un enlace, sino que se carga via AJAX. Si el evento que  abre el modal se asocia al cargar la página, entonces el nuevo contenido que se carga con AJAX no lo tendrá asociado, mientras que si abres el enlace directo a la página sí se asociarán correctamente y por eso funcionarán. Tienes que ver cómo usar eventos delegados

Comment: Es muy getil tu ayuda. Mil gracias por responder y por editar mi post... me disculpo pues soy novato. Exitos y saludos a la distancia. Voy a leer a ver si resuelvo el problema, de lo contrario voy a regresar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He añadido este código a los enlaces `rel="external"` y parece que eso funciona y soluciona el problema:

```
<li>
  <a href="antibioticos.html" rel="external" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right">
    Antibioticos
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Genial. He mirado el enlace y me funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Por favor, acepta esta respuesta como correcta